# c++ template specialization with template<template> member function

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

Why does c++ require a template argument when both `out` member functions (from the template and from the specialization) need a template, because I'm not getting it and google is not helping. Must be c++11 but have the same error with c++1z.
I'm using g++ 7.3.0

getting this error message:

```
error: missing template arguments before ‘>’ token
     Tail::out<P>(o);//<--?!?!?!
```

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

using Out=ostream;

struct O {};

template<typename O=O>
struct Static:public O {
  template<const char** text>
  struct Text {
    static inline void print(Out& o) {o<<text[0];}
  };
};

template<typename O>
struct Endl {
  static inline void print(Out& o) {O::print(o);o<<endl;}
};

template<typename O,typename... OO>
struct MenuData {
  using Head=O;
  using Tail=MenuData<OO...>;
  template<template<typename> class P>
  static inline void out(Out& o) {
    P<O>::print(o);
    Tail::out<P>(o);//<--?!?!?!
  }
};

template<typename O,typename OO>
struct MenuData<O,OO> {
  using Head=O;
  using Last=OO;
  template<template<typename> class P>
  static inline void out(Out& o) {P<O>::print(o);P<Last>::print(o);}
};

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
const char* op1Text="Op1";
using op1=Static<>::Text<&op1Text>;

const char* op2Text="Op2";
using op2=Static<>::Text<&op2Text>;

const char* op3Text="Op3";
using op3=Static<>::Text<&op3Text>;

using MainMenu=MenuData<op1,op2,op3,op1>;

int main(int argc,char** argv) {
  MainMenu::out<Endl>(cout);
  cout<<endl;
}
```

Comment: `Static::Text::out` is a regular member function, not a template, and so doesn't take a template argument.. `MenuData::out` is a template, and so does require a template argument. I'm not sure I quite grasp what it is you find unclear in this example.

Comment: I agree, function names are not helping, so I've changed the regular ones to `print` instead

Comment: So, which part do you find unclear?

Comment: the part with `?!?!?!` i'm calling Tail::out and giving a template<template> as arguments, as defined in both template and specialization and as done in main

Comment: You have `SomeClass::out` call `OtherClass::out`. `out` is a function template, so the call has to provide template arguments for its template parameters. The fact that `SomeClass` and `OtherClass` are two different specializations of the same class template is irrelevant.

Comment: thought that `using Tail=MenuData<OO...>;` was doing it, is it possible to do this?

Comment: Was doing what? Possible to do what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after the code bellow, I found this good question/answer that sheds a light over it

[Where and why do I have to put the "template" and "typename" keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords)

got this working after many hours of testing and checking, still, I'm not happy, this should be simpler, so if anyone has a better solution I would be happy to accept it, AND I still not understanding why the first version was not accepted...

this version compile and prints the desired result, I will go on simply it

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

using Out=ostream;

struct O {};

template<typename O=O>
struct Static:public O {
  template<const char** text>
  struct Text {
    static inline void print(Out& o) {o<<text[0];}
  };
};

template<typename O>
struct Endl {
  static inline void print(Out& o) {O::print(o);o<<endl;}
};

template<typename O,typename... OO>
struct MenuData {
  // using Head=O;
  // using Tail=MenuData<OO...>;
  template<template<typename> class P>
  using X=typename MenuData<OO...>::template OutData<P>;
  template<template<typename> class P>
  struct OutData {
    static inline void out(Out& o) {
      P<O>::print(o);
      X<P>::out(o);//<--?!?!?!
    };
  };
};

template<typename O,typename OO>
struct MenuData<O,OO> {
  // using Head=O;
  // using Last=OO;
  template<template<typename> class P>
  struct OutData {
    static inline void out(Out& o) {
      P<O>::print(o);
      P<OO>::print(o);
    }
  };
};

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
const char* op1Text="Op1";
using op1=Static<>::Text<&op1Text>;

const char* op2Text="Op2";
using op2=Static<>::Text<&op2Text>;

const char* op3Text="Op3";
using op3=Static<>::Text<&op3Text>;

using MainMenu=MenuData<op1,op2,op3,op1>;

int main(int argc,char** argv) {
  MainMenu::OutData<Endl>::out(cout);
  cout<<endl;
}
```

the key point:

```cpp
template<template<typename> class P>
using X=typename MenuData<OO...>::template OutData<P>;
```

so I had to say the obvious again telling that its a template

but using the template parameter

again in `X<P>::out(o);//<--?!?!?!`